# Matches lookbehind / ahead multiple times

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mainTag = "HI";
    String replaceTag = "667";
    String text = "92<HI=/><z==//HIb><cHIhi> ";
    System.out.println(strFormatted(mainTag, replaceTag, text));

    mainTag = "aBc";
    replaceTag = "923";
    text = "<dont replacethis>abcabc< abcabcde >";
    System.out.println(strFormatted(mainTag, replaceTag, text));
}

private static String strFormatted(String mainTag, String replaceTag, String text) {
    return text.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=<)" + mainTag + "(?=.*>)", replaceTag);
}
```

So, I want to replace `mainTag` (variable) for `replaceTag` (variable) **only** inside tags (`<...>`).

In the example above I want to replace the mainTag `HI` (case insensitive) in all occurrences **inside** `<...>` with `667`, but my code only replaces the first occurrence.

**Examples:**

```
92<HI=/><z==//HIb><cHIhi>
```

Expected output:

```
92<667=/><z==//667b><c667667>
```

(mainTag = "HI", replaceTag = "667")

```
<dont replacethis>abcabc<abcabcde>
```

Expected output:

```
<dont replacethis>abcabc<923923de>
```

(mainTag = "aBc", replaceTag = "923");

**Note:** My code is wrong not only because he replaces only 1 time, but also because it only works if the "mainTag" succeeds the "<", in other words, the lookbehind only works for an unique situation.

Comment: Try posting this using code formatting (four spaces at the start of a line or wrapping the code in backticks, i.e., '). The extra \s make this unintelligible.

Comment: You expect hi from `HIb` to be changed to `667b`, but not change `hi` from `replacethis` to `replacet667s`..

Comment: @rock321987 I added more code and info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need look-ahead here. The idea is to find all the `mainTags`, which are followed by a `>`, and then matching pairs of `<>`, and replace with `replaceTag`. The following regex would work:

```
text.replaceAll("(?i)" + mainTag + "(?=[^<>]*>(?:[^<>]*<[^<>]*>)*[^<>]*)$", replaceTag);
```

Explanation:

```
(?i)               # Ignore Case
mainTag            # Match mainTag
(?=                # which is followed by
    [^<>]*         # Some 0 or more characters which are not < or >
    >              # Close the bracket (this ensures, mainTag is between closing bracket
    (?:            # Start a group (to match pair of bracket)
        [^<>]*     # non-bracket characters
        <          # Start a bracket 
        [^<>]*     # non-bracket characters
        >          # End the bracket
    )*             # Match the pair 0 or more times.
    [^<>]*         # Non-bracket characters 0 or more times.
)
[^<>]*)$
```

The above regex really assumes that brackets are always balanced. For unbalanced regex, this might give unexpected results. But then regex is not really the tool for such job.

Otherwise a regex a simple as this would also work fine:

```
"(?i)" + mainTag + "(?=[^<>]*>)"
```

that depends upon your use-case. This doesn't worry about balanced brackets. You can try the second one first, if it fits all scenario, then it's best.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but for the 2nd example it's replacing the first (`abcabc`), but as I said, it must only replace inside the tags < >.

Comment: @developer033 Yeah, I updated the regex. Something was missing. It should work now

Comment: I was going to suggest just `(?=[^<>]*>)` for the lookahead.  I don't see why the rest is needed, especially since it's all optional.

Comment: @AlanMoore To ensure balanced brackets. Otherwise just the simple one would also work

Comment: Thanks, the second regex also works perfect for my case.

Comment: @developer033 Cool. Then I suggest you use the second one only. Easy to tweak later on :)

Comment: I think you have to assume the brackets are balanced for this to work at all.  The long form of your regex is good for quoted strings, or other cases where the same character serves as both opening and closing delimiter.  *That* lookahead needs an anchor at the end, though, to make sure you're counting all the quotes.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yeah right. Forgot the end anchor. And actually that regex assumes the brackets to be balanced.